# $M$ $\mathscr{R}$-submodule complete lattice $\iff$ $aL \subset M \subset a^{-1}L$, $a \in \mathscr{R}$

Tags: number-theory, tensor-products, dedekind-domain

My question may be nestled in the sense that there might be confusion about several notions, please let me know if it is the case.

In "The Arithmetic of Hyperbolic 3-manifolds" by Maclachlan and Reid, the proof of the following Lemma is left as an Exercise:

> Let $L$ be a complete Lattice in $V$ and $M$ an $R$-submodule of $V$. Then $M$ is a complete Lattice $\iff$ there exists $a \in R$ such that $aL \subset M \subset a^{-1}L$

**Note:** $R$ is a Dedekind Domain whose Field of Fraction $k$ is either a number field or a $\mathscr{P}$-adic Field. An $R$-Lattice is a finitely generated $R$-module contained in a vector space $V$ of finite dimension over $k$. Completeness of an $R$-Lattice $L$ is defined through $L \otimes_R k \cong V$.

**My attempt:**

$\implies$ since both are complete, we have $L \otimes_R k \cong M \otimes_R k$ as vector spaces. Therefore, for $l_i,m_i$ bases of $L,M$, we have that $l_i \otimes_R 1$ and $m_i \otimes_R 1$ are bases of their respective spaces and we can can $\alpha_j^i \in k$ such that:
$$ l_i \otimes_R 1 = \sum_j \alpha_j^i \ m_j \otimes_R 1 $$
Since $k$ is the field of fraction, we can express each $\alpha_j^i = n_j^i/d_j^i$ with $n_j^i, d_j^i$ both in $R$.

At this point I get stuck. I figured I could use a method similar to the proof of the gaussian lemma (roughly speaking factoring out the denominators).

But I am falling short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a 2 by 2 example? The entries $\alpha^i_j$ form an invertible change of basis matrix. Mutiply both sides of the equation you wrote by the common denominator of all entries of the matrix, denoted by $a$, we have $$a \cdot l_i\otimes_R 1 = \sum_j (a \cdot \alpha^i_j ) m_j\otimes_R 1,$$ which implies $a\cdot L\subset M$. Invert your equation by the inverse of the matrix of $\alpha^i_j$, you will have $M \subset a^{-1}L$.